# How to explicitly hold lock on java object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have an object that is accessed from multiple threads. I want to implement it so that in order to access its setters and getters, the caller must first explicitly lock it before and then unlock it after finishing. I've though about using synchronized methods but it doesn't seem very straight-forward compared to java's more explicit locking APIs. This is my current stubbed implementation using ReentrantLock.

```
public class Data {
    private ReentrantLock lock;

    private int IntValue;

    public Data() {
        this.IntValue = 0;
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }


    public void Lock() {
        lock.lock();
    }

    public void Unlock() {
        if (!lock.isLocked()) {
            return; 
        }
        //only the thread owning the lock can proceed to unlock
        lock.lock(); 
        int lockCount = lock.getHoldCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < lockCount; i++) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void SetVal(int val) {
        if (!lock.isLocked()) {
            return; 
        }
        lock.lock();
        this.IntValue = val;
    }
}
```

So if a thread wants to call SetVal(int val), it would first have to call Lock() and then call Unlock() when it's done. I've placed isLocked() checks in its setter/getter methods to enforce this rule. And I've added an additional lock call in unlock to make sure only the thread owning the lock can proceed to unlock (an unique feature of ReentrackLock). The object's setters/getters could be called many times before its Unlock() method is called. So in the Unlock() method I have to iterate through its HoldCount and unlock for each count.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient and idiomatic way of achieving this?

Comment: Eh? Just make the methods `synchronized`. No action on the part of callers required at all. Nothing could be more straightforward.

Comment: Wouldn't I lose the lock on the object after each method call? I don't want that. I want to guarantee that a thread has a lock on the object during a sequence of method calls.

Comment: Oh - ok it seems like if I just do a synchronized(data) block and put calls to data's methods inside the block, that would do the trick?

Comment: Correct, just have the caller synchronize on the object.

Comment: Ok, ya...that's for sure easier! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using int value then can go for [AtomicInteger](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicinteger.html)

or make all your method synchronized that you want to prevent from race condition.

or if you want to support both synchronized and normal then you can pit a wrapper like collections.SynchronizedSet.Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the wrong direction with your approach. OOP paradigms state that all data should be kept and managed internally, what you do however is to externalize that control over the internal data by giving it to the caller.

A good design would try to hide the fact that locking is even necessary and do it internally to free the caller from such tasks. Especially because if you transfer the responsibility of proper locking to the caller, then every single caller could be a potential thread issue. If you lock internally however, there is only a single source of potential bugs, so if you encounter an issue you know where to look.

This is how you would do it properly regarding the OOP paradigm:

```
public class Data {
    // protected so it is accessible to derived classes
    // final so the lock object cannot be (accidentally) reassigned
    // Lock (base class) so it is easier to change the implementation later
    protected final Lock lock;

    // clear naming
    private int value;

    public Data() {
        // value is automatically initialized with 0
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    // by convention the setter for ... is set...
    public void setValue(final int value) {
        this.lock.lock();
       // absolutely use try/finally here, to ensure it is unlocked in all cases
        try {
            this.value = value;
        } finally {  
            this.lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // by convention the getter for ... is get...
    public int getValue() {
        this.lock.lock();
        try {
            return this.value;
        } finally {
            this.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```